# Is there a jQuery alternative to position: sticky?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Let's say I'm making a bootstrap 4 layout with two col-lg-6 divs. The left one contains an image and the right one contains a bunch of text, long enough to make the page scrollable.
Since the grid in bootstrap 4 is based on the flex display property, the left div automatically stretches vertically to the height of the right one.
Bootstrap 4 has a new "sticky-top" class which uses position: sticky.
So, if "sticky-top" class is added to the image inside the left div and the page is scrolled down, the image scrolls with the page until it reaches the top of the page and then it sticks to the top and stays sticky until the bottom of its parent div reaches the bottom of the image, and then the image continues scrolling along with the page.
Unfortunately, position: sticky is still not fully supported in all modern browsers, so I was wondering if there is a cross-browser compatible jQuery alternative to it?
I tried adding an extra class to the image via jquery that changes the position to fixed in css and is added to the image when the image reaches the top of the page, and then I tried removing it after the footer comes into viewport, but that makes the image disappear from the viewport instead of scrolling along with the page because it bounces back to the top of its parent div after the additional class is removed from it.

```
<header>header sticks to top</header>
<div>breadcrumbs that scroll along with the page go here</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
    <img src="image.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="image">
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
    <p>Bunch of random text long enough to make the page scrollable goes here</p>
  </div>
</div>
<footer>Footer stuff goes here</footer>
```

Note: the image should be sticky only on large and extra large grids and I would prefer to not have to use any plugins.

Comment: yeah, that's entirely possible with javascript (even if you sprinkle in some jquery.) Under some condition, make it fixed or not fixed.

Comment: Have you tried it with `sticky-top`? If so, please post the code so I understand what you're trying to make sticky.

Comment: Everything I tried so far is crap so it's not worth posting. I need to stick the image to top after the page is scrolled and unstick it after the footer reaches the viewport. Basically the same thing as they have it on the apple.com on this page http://www.apple.com/shop/buy-mac/macbook-pro?product=MLH42LL/A&step=config#

Comment: I wrote this really quickly in case you can adapt it to your project. http://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/egxXjd

Comment: It works. I just need to tweak the offsets a little bit. Thanks.

Comment: You can use jQuery. Something like this: http://www.codeply.com/go/pUklCbhAfo

Comment: @GoranTesic great, want me to submit that as an answer?

Comment: Sure. Go ahead, I'll accept it.

Comment: Btw, it has a minor bug with responsive grid. When the browser is resized and the bootstrap grid changes to smaller grid it kinda jitters up and down when the class is added and removed, and when the page is refreshed on smaller grid and then the browser is resized to larger grid, it doesn't stick to top after you scroll the page up from the bottom;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wrote this really quickly. Add class `.sticky` to the thing you want to be sticky, and add class `.stickyTo` the parent that you want it to be sticky to. It isn't perfect, but gives the general concept and maybe you can tweak it for your project.

```js
var $sticky = $('.sticky'),
  $stickyTo = $('.stickyTo'),
  stickyToTop = $stickyTo.offset().top,
  stickyToBottom = stickyToTop + $stickyTo.outerHeight();

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(),
    stickyTop = $sticky.offset().top,
    stickyBottom = $sticky.offset().top + $sticky.outerHeight();
  
  if (stickyBottom >= stickyToBottom) {
    if (scroll < stickyTop) {
      $sticky.addClass('fixed').removeClass('abs');
    } else {
      $sticky.addClass('abs');
    }
  } else if (scroll > stickyToTop) {
    $sticky.addClass('fixed');
  } else if (scroll < stickyToTop) {
    $sticky.removeClass('abs').removeClass('fixed');
  }
});
```

```css
.row {
  background: #ccc;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: auto;
}

.abs {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<header>header sticks to top</header>
<div>breadcrumbs that scroll along with the page go here</div>
<div class="row stickyTo">
  <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
    <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" class="img-fluid sticky" alt="image">
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
    <p>Bunch of random text long enough to make the page scrollable goes here</p><p>Bunch of random text long enough to make the page scrollable goes here</p><p>Bunch of random text long enough to make the page scrollable goes here</p><p>Bunch of random text long enough to make the page scrollable goes here</p><p>Bunch of random text long enough to make the page scrollable goes here</p><p>Bunch of random text long enough to make the page scrollable goes here</p><p>Bunch of random text long enough to make the page scrollable goes here</p><p>Bunch of random text long enough to make the page scrollable goes here</p><p>Bunch of random text long enough to make the page scrollable goes here</p><p>Bunch of random text long enough to make the page scrollable goes here</p><p>Bunch of random text long enough to make the page scrollable goes here</p><p>Bunch of random text long enough to make the page scrollable goes here</p><p>Bunch of random text long enough to make the page scrollable goes here</p><p>Bunch of random text long enough to make the page scrollable goes here</p><p>Bunch of random text long enough to make the page scrollable goes here</p>
  </div>
</div>
<footer>Footer stuff goes here</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks. I turned it into a function and called it both on $(document).ready and $(window).resize to prevent the browser resizing bugs with responsive grid.

Comment: @GoranTesic nice, glad it helped.